# WebAPI - add check before executing route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Restier to generate oData from a dataset. All works great.

```
public async static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    await config.MapRestierRoute<EntityFrameworkApi<uData>>(
    "uData",
    "/api/uData",
    new RestierBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
}
```

I need to perform custom code based on a part of the URL like /id/api/uData

How do I add a controller to make a simple check and then continue executing the restier route?

So I want a check before sending away the oData and I simply need a simple controller checking stuff based on an id as part of the URL.

How on earth can I do this - can't find it anywhere. A small sample code would be so nice.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [action filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs).

```
public class YourActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         // Write Preprocessing logic here
    }
}
```

You can use this attribute either at Action level or Controller level like this

```
[YourActionFilter]
public Action Login(...)
{
    // Your action code here
}
```

Comment: How can I do this with Restier - do you know that?